# CSS border over all nested ion-nav-views

Tags: css, nested, ionic-framework

I'm not good at styling so I will ask straight ahead:
how do I draw a border over the whole web application's UI composed of nested views (ion-nav-view)?

My initial try was to set a class on a body:

```
<body ng-class="{'noConnection': hiresUnavail}" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

this is being produced now:

[image]

now, you can see a top-left corner of the web browser. The orange line is the desired border defined in the body tag as you can see upper. So what should I do in order to see this border all round the borders even on the top of the nested ng-views?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your HTML - at least the related sections?  It's very hard to know how to apply the CSS without the target HTML.

Comment: please, understand, that there is multiple nested views. I won't post all the html of views being nested, because that's not a good way to solve this. and they can change. even level of nesting can change. I need to set this on top-most level in index.html. there you have just body tag and ion-nav-view in it.